# Running a docker image, produced from a Dockerfile, does not do anything

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I use this Dockefile copied from [here](https://baykara.medium.com/installing-clang-10-in-a-docker-container-4c24a4538af2)

```
#we are using ubuntu base image
FROM ubuntu:18.04
# installing requirements to get and extract prebuilt binaries
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
 xz-utils \
 curl \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
#Getting prebuilt binary from llvm 
RUN curl -SL https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/download/llvmorg-10.0.0/clang+llvm-10.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz \
 | tar -xJC . && \
 mv clang+llvm-10.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04 clang_10 && \
 echo ‘export PATH=/clang_10/bin:$PATH’ >> ~/.bashrc && \
 echo ‘export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/clang_10/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH’ >> ~/.bashrc
#start the container from bash
CMD [ “/bin/bash” ]
```

Then I run

```
docker build -t clang_10 .
```

It works. With the clang_10 image well created.

But then I run

```
docker run -it clang_10
```

Nothing happens! The console does not switch to a Linux prompt as expected. Where do things go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the types of quotes: Use `"` instead of `“`.

Change the last line from

```
CMD [ “/bin/bash” ]
```

to

```
CMD [ "/bin/bash" ]
```

Comment: I suppose the single quotes in echo command (`‘`) should also be replaced on `'`

Comment: @DennisMeissel Well spotted! Yes indeed, the `‘` in the RUN should be replaced with `'`.

Answer (score -1):

change the CMD to CMD [ "/bin/bash" ] or ["/bin/sh"]

Comment: Please do not duplicate an existing answer, vote up that instead.